# stretched or zoomed in background photo in responsive width ; how to fix this

Tags: html, css

I have created a responsive website.http://www.kupa-flyfishing.com/
On a mobile device the background photo is zoomed in / stretched.

In the header section I have CSS which set the viewport and the background image:

#### CSS:

```css
header {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(img/hero.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Grz,
Lino

Comment: It doesnt look stretched/zoomed to me...http://i.imgur.com/fs4Dukc.png

Comment: You're setting the height to 100vh which is the viewport height, and then telling the background to cover (so that no whitespace is left). This means that the height of the image will also be 100vh while maintaining the aspect ratio. Try `contain` instead? Not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Hi Dave, what kind of phone did you use?